# grep command for web sever log filefor extracting http response code

Tags: bash, grep

I want to extract http status code from this using bash . Please suggest a grep command.

```
devel.example.com:80 199.4.27.122 - - [10/Oct/2012:04:45:09 -0400] "GET /wp-content/themes/cordobo-green-park-2/img/logo-cgp2.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1863 "http://devel.example.com/category/bit-lug/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.92 Safari/537.4"
```

Comment: any effort from your end?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lines are in a file called `requests.log`, and all rows look like you described, you can use this command:

```
sed -E 's|.*HTTP/1.1" ([0-9]+).*|\1|' requests.log
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please feel free to accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk -F "HTTP/1.?" '{split($2,a," ");print a[2]}' file
200
```

It will get the first number after `HTTP/1.1`

Comment: There may well be `HTTP/1.0` clients in the log as well if it's a public server.

Answer (score 0):

I might do something like

```
$ cat input
devel.example.com:80 199.4.27.122 - - [10/Oct/2012:04:45:09 -0400] "GET
/wp-content/themes/cordobo-green-park-2/img/logo-cgp2.png HTTP/1.1" 200
1863 "http://devel.example.com/category/bit-lug/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.92
Safari/537.4"
$ grep -oP '(?<=HTTP\/1\.1"\s)\d+' input
200
```